# Vivid Vivado sed coloring for Batch and TCL mode

Tags: bash, sed, vivado

I've written a Bash function that uses `sed` to inject coloring of Vivado. The interactive TCL mode works but I find my self writing in the dark due to the `sed` pipe (I guess).

Is there any way to get the input presented while typing through the sed?

```
function vivid_vivado() {
   mode="batch"
   args=""
   trace="-notrace"

   for var in $*
   do
      gui)   mode=$var    ;;
      tcl)   mode=$var    ;;
      batch) mode=$var    ;;
      trace) trace=""     ;;
      *)     args+="$var ";;
   done
   vivado -mode $mode -source MY_SCRIPT.tcl $trace -tclargs $args | \
     sed -Ee "s/(^INFO:)/$(echo -e '\033[2m')\1$(echo -e '\033[0m')/g"
}
```

I run multiple prasers `sed -Ee ... -e ...` which works really well. Unfortunately, I'm writing from a Windows machine at the moment, so the code should be considered unverified.

Is it possible to get the tcl input line to propagate trough the `sed` command? The cli looks like `Vivado% USERINPUT` when in interactive mode if that would help.

*Runing in interactive tcl mode normaly leaves you with at a row `Vivado%` where you are allowed to contine to interact with Vivado. Here your keybord inputs are registerd and propagated to stdout while typing and executed by Vivado up on an ENTER press. 
You can run `vivado -mode batch` to spot the difference when interacting)*

When in TCL interactive mode `mode=tcl`; after the script is done you are left on a blank row and allowed to contine to interact with Vivado but your typing will not show until ENTER is pressed. Is There any way to get around this?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by the TCL input line or exactly which part you are confused about. I tested your sed command, btw, and it works fine on Linux.

Comment: I''ll update the text. The problem is that when the `source MY_SCRIPT` is done in interactive tcl mode `mode=tcl` you are able to interact with vivado. It works fine but you will not get your typing to show in the console, while typing. It shows up on an Enter press.

Comment: You may need help from someone who knows Vivado. Your sed script, by the way, just colors the "INFO:" string at the start of the line in grey. I'm not really understanding why that would be helpful.

Comment: I use it to find relevant things in the output. I use different colors for different stuff. Making INFO gray in this example code is just to show the consept, a trivial usecase. Think like code highlighting its just to make it easier to navigate the text.

Comment: Ok good luck with it. I'm sure it will make more sense to someone who has used Vivado.